# Different results on the basis of different foreign key value using a falg in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Please see attached image.

[alt text http://img241.imageshack.us/img241/3585/customcost.png](http://img241.imageshack.us/img241/3585/customcost.png)

Can you please tell me what query will work. Please ignore isdefinite and productpriceid columns.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the two answers below? Is our interpretation of your problem correct?

Comment: Both answers are correct. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single query, this should do it if I've interpreted your question properly:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT t1.SupplierVenueProductID, [...]
FROM    table t1
        LEFT JOIN
                table t2
                ON t1.SupplierVenueProductID = t2.SupplierVenueProductID
                AND t2.iscustomcost = 1
WHERE   t2.SupplierVenueProductID IS NULL
OR      t1.iscustomcost = 1
```

I don't know your table name, but you join it to itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit lost on what you want to accomplish here, 
going by your requirement *if isCustomCost = 1 then return record #3 from SupplierVenueProductId 1 and both records from SupplierVenueProductId 2*

Trying to generalize this, I think what you *need* is :

*return all rows from the table, unless when there is a record for a SupplierVenueProductId that has isCustomCost = 1, then only return that record for this SupplierVenueProductId*

Which then becomes something along the lines of :

```
SELECT t1.* 
  FROM myTable t1
 WHERE t1.isCustomCost = 1
    OR NOT EXISTs (SELECT *
                     FROM t2
                    WHERE t2.SupplierVenueProductId = t1.SupplierVenueProductId
                      AND t2.isCustomCost = 1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was my interpretation as well. The join and subquery approaches to his problem - either should work.